# Android execute when multiple tasks are done

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an app that downloads information from my server after an NFC card has been detected.

When a card is detected, I start
- an Asynctask to download some data from my server
- an animation of a popup appearing on the screen

After both the asynctask and the animation are done, I want to start a method that displays the downloaded data in the popup.

What is the correct way to trigger this new method? It can only start when both conditions are met.

Comment: What is "an animation of a popup"? Do you mean a popup appearing in an animated way? If so, how long does it take? Or do you mean a popup displaying an animated graphic of some sort? Again, if so, how long does it take to complete?

Comment: I mean a popup appearing in an animated way. It takes about a second. But if the data is loaded in less then a second, the animation gets interupted, and it doesn't look fluid anymore

Comment: So have the `AsyncTask` save the data to a global field using `onPostExecute(...)` then have the popup load the data from that field when it's animation is finished if the field isn't `null`. To compensate for a delayed download, have a method in the popup class which can be called by the `onPostExecute(...)` method of the `AsyncTask` to notify the popup that the data is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you `Animation` object has the method `setAnimationLister`. It takes as parameter a Class Object that implements the interface `Animation.AnimationListener` . This interface requires three methods to be implemented:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
```

The `onAnimationEnd` is triggered when the animation ends. If I have not misunderstood you, this is what you need

EDIT:

you could have two booleans value, `boolean animationFinished = false, downloadFinished = false`;  When `onPostExecute` is called put `downloadFinished` to true and call `yourMethod`.
When `onAnimationEnd` is triggered `animationFinished = true` and call `yourMethod`. `yourMethod`  should start like:

```
if (!animationFinished || !downloadFinished)
 return;
```

Comment: This is indeed what I need, but my question goes a little further:
How can I start a method when **both** the animation and the Asynctask are done?

My current aproach is to declare 2 booleans and check in both onAnimationEnd and onPostExecute

Comment: I had the same idea. I don`t now if a better approach exists

Answer (score 1):

In the async task you use to download data add the onPostExecute method to remove the animation popup and show the downloaded data as well like this :

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     //put code to disable animation popup
     //code for displaying downloaded data popup
 }
```

For more info check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: The problem is that I want the animation to complete before displaying the downloaded data. Most of the time, the data is loaded faster than the duration of the animation

Comment: Then you can just define a global boolean. Then in the doinbackground of async task of downloading data use the while loop to check if the animation has completed. And in the onPostExecute of animation change the value of boolean